# Chrome: doesn't print javascript content

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, printing, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

( This is through Grease/Tampermonkey ).

Here's a print function for a kiosk using the Chrome beta browser:

```
$("#autoCheckOrder button").click ( function () {
    var newWin      = window.open (""); 
    newWin.document.write ( "<!DOCTYPE html>" );
    newWin.document.write( "<html>" );
    newWin.document.write( "<head>" );
    newWin.document.write( "<title>" );
    newWin.document.write( "</title>" );
    newWin.document.write( "<style>" );
    newWin.document.write( "@media print { " );
    newWin.document.write( "body { " );
    newWin.document.write( "background-color: white;" );
    newWin.document.write( "width: 55mm;" );
    newWin.document.write( "position: absolute;" );
    newWin.document.write( "top: 0;" );
    newWin.document.write( "left: 0;" );
    newWin.document.write( "padding: 0px;" );
    newWin.document.write( "font-size: 14px;" );
    newWin.document.write( "line-height: 18px;" );
    newWin.document.write( "}" );
    newWin.document.write( "}" );
    newWin.document.write( "</style>" );
    newWin.document.write( "</head>" );
    newWin.document.write( "<body>" );
    newWin.document.write ( loanHTML ); 
    newWin.document.write( "</body>" );
    newWin.document.write( "</html>" );
    if(newWin.print()) {
        newWin.close();
    } else {
        newWin.close();
    }
});
```

It grabs a table from the a page listing all items, then creates a
'receipt'. The receipt is then printed. This worked perfectly for a while, now it only prints the first item.

I have tried the following with absolutely no results:

- Using page-break-after: always
- Placing receipt in div with the above CSS rule
- Reinstalling the printer
- Paper reduction settings for printer

The crazy thing is that it used to print all items flawlessly and now it doesn't. I even re-installed the script from a backup just to be sure.

No idea where to go from here. All content shows in print preview, but only the first item prints. 'Header and footer' setting only makes things worse, not better.

**UPDATE**

I changed the HTML sent to the printer and it works. Still not sure if it's entirely valid but it's printing. I'll know what to fix if it stops printing. Thanks for the input!

Comment: Why are you trying to do this in JavaScript. This is wrong.

Comment: No choice. 3rd party internal app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only plausible explanation I can see is that your loanHTML variable is empty or undefined.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/waitinforatrain/bMzUt/2/

Comment out the `var loanHTML` line and run again, and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: It works in Greasemonkey/Firefox. It is a table and for some reason only the first row prints in Chrome though the whole thing shows up in print preview. Wondering if I should write th whole thing to a hidden div on the page before writing to the receipt page.

Comment: Actually, the `loanHTML` is probably malformed.  FF and Chrome handle malformed code differently, and Chrome also "stringizes" things differently.  Save a malfunctioning print-page to disc.  Then open that file with Chrome and verify it (still) has the problem.  Repeat until you have a problem-demo file.  Then upload that file to http://pastebin.com/ and point us to it.  ... Also, ***exactly*** how is `loanHTML` defined/set?

Comment: I think you are definitely on to something. The div is pulled from within a table thus stripping the outer table tags. I didn't bother doing anything about this as it seemed to work fine ...at first ...then promptly forgot about that small detail. Still wondering why it worked to begin with.

Comment: Brock Adams ~ Yep, invalid html. Works now. Thanks!